# How to target a specific instance of a class from a string variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have a program where I need to get information from one of many instances of a class from just a string variable.

I've asked a programmer friend of mine for help but he's specialised in C# rather than python3 so the best he could offer was to try using the exec() command. This didn't really help me.

Say I have some code setting up information about cars

```py
class Cars:
    def __init__(self, Brand, Model, Owner):
        self.Brand = Brand
        self.Model = Model
        self.Owner = Owner

Car1 = Cars("Honda", "Civic", "Jon Arbuckle")

Car2 = Cars("Ford", "Focus", "Martha Jones")

MysteryCar = "Car1"
```

Is there anyway to return the value `"Jon Arbuckle"` from only knowing what's stored in `MysteryCar`?

Comment: This is what dictionaries are for.

Comment: Dict or ```locals()/globals()``` which is a dict anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

using `locals()` which is a dict of you local scope's variables' names (as strings) as its keys and their values as.....well its values!

```
print(locals()[MysteryCar].Owner)
```

Another alternative would be to use `eval` which is a method that evaluates a string as python code. So you could do something like:

```py
print(eval(MysteryCar).Owner)
```

But in general `eval` is considered risky and should be avoided, in my opinion...

For example if your `MysteryCar` is an input from the user that could lead to serious problems if the user puts in some dangerous command.

On the other hand, using `locals` you could let the user know if his selection is wrong using `try/except KeyError`

Answer (score 2):

Your friend is correct. You can use `exec` to run some Python code which you define using the string that `MysteryCar` is pointing to. I like f-strings (Python 3.6+) but you can format your strong in other ways, too:

```
>>> command = f"car_owner = {MysteryCar}.Owner"
>>> exec(command)
>>> print(car_owner)
Jon Arbuckle
```

`MysteryCar` will evaluate to `Car1` inside the f-string, so you're executing the command

```
car_owner = Car1.Owner
```

above.

As some comments pointed out, however, I would question whether this is the best solution to the problem, or if you should just use a dictionary.